# C++ simple two-dimensional array overwritten by last input

Tags: c++

So I've run into a problem while writing this simple line of code for a school project. What happens is that after asking for user input to fill an array with values, the input for the last column overwrites all the other columns. I've tried finding the problem myself but I just can't seem to find it!

Part of the code that I think is problematic:

```
for (col = 0; col < arraywidth; col++) {
    for (row = 0; row < arrayheight; row++) {
        cout << "Please input a value for element " << col << ", " << row << "." << endl;
        cin >> T[col][row];
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help. Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // ------------- Variables ---------------------------------
    int arrayheight, arraywidth, col, row, maxe, pos_c, T[arrayheight][arraywidth];
    // ---------------------------------------------------------




    // ------------- Array Creation & Filling ------------------
    cout << "Please insert the height of the array." << endl;
    cin >> arrayheight;
    cout << "Please insert the width of the array." << endl;
    cin >> arraywidth;
    cout << "Now we will be inputting values in the two-dimensional array." << endl;

    for (col = 0; col < arraywidth; col++) {
        for (row = 0; row < arrayheight; row++) {
            cout << "Please input a value for the element " << col << ", " << row << "." << endl;
            cin >> T[col][row];
        }
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------- Displaying the Array ----------------------
    cout << "Now we will be displaying the array." << endl;

    for (col = 0; col < arraywidth; col++) {
            cout << endl;
        for (roaw = 0; row < arrayheight; row++) {
                cout << T[col][row] << " | ";
        }
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------- Logical Function as Requested -------------
    cout << " " << endl;
    for (col = 0; col < arraywidth; col++) {
            maxe = -99;
        for (row = 0; row < arrayheight; row++) {
            if (T[col][row] > maxe) {
                maxe = T[col][row];
                pos_c = col;
            }
        }
        cout << "The maximum value of the column " << col << " " << "is " << maxe << endl;
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Picture of what happens:

[image]

Comment: Links to information required to interpret the question render the question useless in the long term because links rot. Prefer instead to produce a [mcve] and place the MCVE in the question. As an added bonus, the act of producing the MCVE often exposes the error to you and allows you to fix it without asking a question.

Comment: PS: I don't see anything wrong with the code in the question. You sure you have correctly allocated all of the storage for `T`?

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does: `int arrayheight, arraywidth, col, row, maxe, pos_c, T[arrayheight][arraywidth];`

Comment: okay thanks for the help everyone. will try to use mcve next time. i blame my school teacher for explaining arrays first without getting me into memory allocation first

Comment: Barmar got  here before I could get back to this, but for future reference a MCVE for this problem could look like https://ideone.com/qZKf8t It's hard to say though because allocatingingn array around uninialized variables results in undefined behaviour. Making the MCVE could result in the compiler electing to do something different from what your full code example did. This is the great curse of Undefined behaviour: What happens isn't defined and can change from run to run or simply by adding or removing an unrelated line of code. It's nasty smurf to have to track down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the declaration of the array `t[arrayheight][arraywidth]` before you assign to those variables. You need to move that declaration down to after the variables are read from the user.

Also, C++ doesn't allow variable-length arrays -- that's a G++ extension. You should use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or dynamic allocation with `new`.